# How can I fix this error 'no matching function for call'?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, unique-ptr

Given the following code:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Obj>> objs;
    std::string str;
    Obj obj;
    std::unique_ptr<Obj> objUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(obj));
    objs.insert({ str, objUniquePtr });   <<<<<<<< ERROR
```

I get the following error:

`no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Obj> >::insert(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: On a side note - default-constructing a local `Obj` instance just to `new` another `Obj` instance with it is redundant. Use `std::unique_ptr<Obj> objUniquePtr(new Obj);` instead, or better: `auto objUniquePtr = std::make_unique<Obj>();`

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to copy construct a `std::unique_ptr`, which is not allowed since `std::unique_ptr`s cannot be copy constructed. Move construct it instead and use the `emplace` member function, to make sure no copy construction of a `std::unique_ptr` takes place:

```
objs.emplace({str, std::move(objUniquePtr)}); //notice the move operation
```

This will solve your error. Just make sure you don't try to access or dereference `objUniquePtr` after the move operation, as you'll be trying to dereference a `nullptr`.

Comment: now I get the following error: `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<Obj>]’
    _M_value_field(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) { }`

Comment: Better to use `emplace()` instead: `objs.emplace(str, std::move(objUniquePtr));` or even `objs.emplace(str, std::make_unique<Obj>());`

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I missed that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: To clarify, a `std::unique_ptr` is always set to `nullptr` after being moved from.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Correct (for all major compilers, as far as I'm aware), but strictly speaking, accessing any object after moving from it is undefined behaviour

Comment: @AzamBham No it is not. It's up to the type to decide what guaranties to provide. Virtually all types guarantee the moved-from object is destructible and assignable. Doing otherwise would make the type basically unusable. Other types may provide additional guaranties. `std::unique_ptr` is required to be a `nullptr` after being moved. It is a relatively common approach to make the moved-from state equivalent to the default constructed state. Edit : The only part of accessing `obj` that is UB is dereferencing a `nullptr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP63-CPP.+Do+not+rely+on+the+value+of+a+moved-from+object - I stand corrected. I'll edit the post, again.

Comment: I would advise you that the term "Standard Template Library" used in the linked documentation is inaccurate. There is no part of the standard library known as the Standard Template Library. That is the name of a library from the early days of C++, of which many parts were included into the standard library we know today. Any mention of STL or Standard Template Library is a misnomer, unless it refers to this precursor library.

Comment: That is an interesting set of guidelines you've shared. I will certainly refer to it in the future.